# Splitting survey data with OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe with results from a survey where there were options A-E and it was possible to select more than one option - a selection could be 'A' or 'A;C;D', etc.

I will be using the data for some machine learning and am looking to run it through `OneHotEncoder` to end up with the 5 columns with 1's and 0's.

An example of my initial survey data is :

```
survey_data = pd.DataFrame({'Q1':  ['A','B','C','A;D', 'D;E', 'F']})
```

I initially tried `LabelEncoder` but obviously ended up with a lot of features (rather than just the A-E).

[image: Final results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [MultilabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) for this:

```
inputX = [element.split(';') for element in survey_data['Q1']]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
transformedX = mlb.fit_transform(inputX)

#Out: transformedX
#array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, using [get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# example data provided by OP
survey_data = pd.DataFrame({'Q1':  ['A','B','C','A;D', 'D;E', 'F']})

# split out rows with multiple chosen options into columns
tmp = survey_data.Q1.str.split(';').apply(pd.Series)

# one-hot encode columns with get_dummies, then overlay into one df
df = (pd.get_dummies(tmp[0])
        .add(pd.get_dummies(tmp[1]), fill_value=0)
        .astype(int))

print(df)

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  0  0  0
3  1  0  0  1  0  0
4  0  0  0  1  1  0
5  0  0  0  0  0  1
```